# Compare two fields and produce results based on it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I found this portal online and I'm hoping to find some help with Microsoft Excel.

I have the below scenario. I want to print 1 if the due date is lesser than the closed date and 0 if it's more than the closed date. Is this possible to achieve in excel?

```
Closed date     Due date              Result
5/3/2019 9:58   5/5/2019 4:22          1 (if Due Date is less than Closed date)
                                       0 (if Due Date is more than Closed date)
```

Comment: If the closed date is in `A1` and the due date is in `B1`, perhaps `=--(B1<A1)`. Note that this returns 0 if the two are equal, which is a scenario you didn't cover.

Comment: hmm...we can assign a different value it that's the case. it's my first time with excel macros so pardon my mistakes. thanks for your response Ben

Comment: May you post a screenshot of the data, please?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! Excel is good for what you need, the formula you're looking for can be something like that:

```
=IF(B1<A1,1,0)
```

Where "Due Date" is located in cell B1 and "Closed Date" is located in cell A1.

Take into account that in case that "Due Date" and "Closed Date" are equal the formula will return 0. If you want the formula to return 1 in case of equal date, the formula should be like that:

```
=IF(B1<=A1,1,0)
```

Comment: t appreciate your help here. when i tried to plot the above formula in my excel it just don't seem to work due to some bizarre reason. I highly value your help here :)

Comment: @nancy_olson is your install of excel set to use the semi-colon ";" instead of the comma ","? so try =IF(B1<=A1;1;0)